# Getting two Navigation bar when landing to final destination - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Below is my current code but by using this code I am getting two Navigation Bar in Class B, how to remove second Navigation Bar.

I am thinking this is happening because from my Parent class I am pushing to Class A and it already has navigationView and then for Class A to Class B navigation I am again using NavigationStack and navigationDestination, thats why I have two NavBars.
I replaced my Parent class code with

```
let classA = ClassA()
let navigateToClassA = UIHostingController(rootView: classA)
let swiftUIView = navigateToClassA.view!
swiftUIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addChild(navigateToClassA) 
view.addSubview(swiftUIView)
swiftUIView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
swiftUIView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
swiftUIView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
swiftUIView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

**but still getting NavBar on Class A which has NavigationTitle of Parent class and doesn't have back button, I do need back button in Class A and Class B with right title**

My Parent View Controller which is UIKit and has tableView,
when user will click on specific row I am showing swiftUI screen which is Class A

Parent class to Class A navigation code is

```
let classA = ClassA()
let navigateToClassA = UIHostingController(rootView: classA)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigateToClassA, animated: true)
```

Now I am landing to Class A and below is Class A code

```
struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var isChildViewPresented: Bool = false
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 7) {
                    Text("user 1")
                    Text("Long Press Here")
                        .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2) {
                            isChildViewPresented = true
                        }
                    Text("User 2")
                }
                .padding()
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isChildViewPresented) {
                    classB()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Class A")
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my Class B code which will show when I will navigate from onLongPressGesture in Class A

```
struct classB: View {

var body: some View {
VStack(alignment: .leading){
     Text("Hello")
  }
  .navigationTitle("Class B")
 }
}
```